# Project ending total by lot between 2 data sets

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that pulls component usage for a raw material by production order (MR #).  Below I will use 514 pounds of item IM02811 on 8/2.  There is no lot picked or assigned to be consumed for MR56333 yet (we have to predict what will be used based on expiration date).

```
Select 'Comp. Usage' as Flag
     , '2' as Sort
     , [Item No_]
     , [Location Code] as 'Loc'
     , [Prod_ Order No_] as 'Doc. No.'
     , -SUM([Remaining Qty_ (Base)]) as 'Qty'
     , [Due Date]
      , '' as ExpDate
     , '' as 'Contract'
     , '' as 'Ship Mthd'
From OIC_LIVE.dbo.[Oregon Ice Cream$Prod_ Order Component]
Where Status in ('1','2','3')
 and [Item No_] = 'IM02811'
 and [Remaining Quantity] <> 0
Group By [Item No_], [Location Code], [Prod_ Order No_], [Due Date]
```

[image]
Here is my current inventory of item IM02811 by lot # (Doc No) with expiration date.

```
Select 'Expire' as Flag
     , '2' as Sort
     , ia.[Item No_]
     --, ia.[Location Code] as 'Loc'
     , ia.[Lot No_] as 'Doc No'
     , Sum(ia.[Available Qty_ (Base)]) as 'Qty'
     , ExpDt.[Expiration Date] as 'ExpDate'
     , '' as Contract
     , '' as 'Ship Mthd'
From OIC_LIVE.dbo.[Oregon Ice Cream$Item Availability View] ia
Left Outer Join (Select [Item No_]
                     , [Lot No_]
                     , Max([Entry No_]) as EntryNo
                     , [Expiration Date]
                From OIC_LIVE.dbo.[Oregon Ice Cream$Item Ledger Entry]
                Where [Expiration Date] <> '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                Group by [Item No_]
                    , [Lot No_]
                    , [Expiration Date]) ExpDt
 On ia.[Item No_] = ExpDt.[Item No_]
 and ia.[Lot No_] = ExpDt.[Lot No_]
Where  ExpDt.[Expiration Date] >= Getdate()
 and ia.[Item No_] = 'IM02811'
Group by ia.[Item No_]
     --, ia.[Location Code] 
     , ia.[Lot No_] 
     , ExpDt.[Expiration Date]
```

[image]

Assuming First Expiring First Out (FEFO), I need to predict lot usage and calculate remaining inventory.  In this example, we will all 50 of lot F021287 and 464.26191 pounds of lot F022667 to provide the 514.26191 pounds the order calls for.  In other words, we will consume all but 535.7381 of Lot F02267.  I need my SQL to return the 535.7381 by lot(s) as projected inventory after schedule projection.

[image]

This is the dumbed down example…imagine a dozen scheduled production orders and a dozen lots with different expiration dates I need to mathematically subtract out by FEFO as projected consumption.  I feel like I might be looking at a cursor to line up the prod orders and start performing math down on each lot to predict future inventory by each lot.  Once projected out, I can simply return lots that were not projected to be used and their expiration dates.

Comment: There is no question here... what is your question?

Comment: Next to last paragraph "I need the SQL to return 535 by lot as projected inventory after scheduled projectsion."  See visual below that under "Report shows projected inventory after scheduled production."  That is the answer I need.  Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an SQL writing service.  Here we help with questions on existing code.  If you have a code example that is not working the way you expect we can help.  If you need code written for you then hire a consultant.

Comment: Thats fair, perhaps I misrepresented the question.  I was simply looking for a suggestion on how to approach the problem.  At first I thought a cursor, now I am dumping the data into a temp table and looping over it.  Logically it should work fine once I narrow down the syntax.  If I can't figure that part out I will add to the post.  In the meantime I am open to process suggestions to accomplish the goal.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Comp)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Comp_item = #Comp.[item no_]
             , @Comp_Qty = #Comp.Qty
             , @orig_qty = #comp.qty
             , @mr = #Comp.[Doc. No.]
    From #Comp

    --SELECT 'Looking for ';
    WHILE @Comp_Qty > 0
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #inv WHERE #Inv.[Item No_] = @Comp_item)
            BREAK

        SELECT TOP 1 @smallest_qty = qty, @smallest_doc = [Doc No]
        FROM #Inv 
        WHERE #Inv.[Item No_] = @Comp_item
        ORDER BY #Inv.ExpDate   

        --SELECT @Comp_Qty AS qty, @smallest_doc AS inv_doc, @smallest_qty AS inv_qty;
        --SELECT * FROM #inv;
        --if (SELECT TOP 1 qty FROM #inv ) < @Comp_Qty 
        if @smallest_qty <= @Comp_Qty 
        BEGIN
            SET @Comp_Qty = @Comp_Qty - @smallest_qty;
            DELETE FROM #inv WHERE [Doc no] = @smallest_doc;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Qty in inventory is larger than needed
            UPDATE #inv
            SET qty = qty - @Comp_Qty 
            WHERE [Doc No] = @smallest_doc;

            SET @Comp_Qty = 0;
        END
    END
    DELETE FROM #Comp WHERE @Comp_item = #Comp.[item no_] and @orig_qty = #Comp.Qty and @mr = #Comp.[Doc. No.]
END
```

Comment: I have some comments... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the comment above -- putting in a temp table is better than a cursor, even better is to find a way to have no loops at all -- SQL is a language that works with sets of data and you have to think in sets not in flow of control and loops.

For example, vis-a-vis your code above you can use left joins to reduce the need for loops like this:

```
SELECT C.[item no_] AS ITEM_NO, C.Qty AS QTY, C.[Doc. No.] AS DOC_NUM,
       I.QTY AS SMALLEST_QTY
From #Comp AS C
LEFT JOIN (
   -- Here we select smallest by date  
   SELECT QTY, [Doc No] AS DOC_NUM, [Item No_] AS ITEM_NO,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item No_] ORDER BY ExpDate AS RN
   FROM #Inv 
) I ON I.ITEM = C.COMP_ITEM AND RN = 1
```

Now you can look at this set and see where SMALLEST_QTY is less than QTY

Note: I did not "test" this, or look carefully at all your rules... this is just supposed to show you how SQL can be used to manipulate sets instead of single records.

Another note -- and you might not be able to change this -- but your names are not good.  There really is no reason to have spaces and upper and lower case in the column names. It just makes it harder to work with.  Whatever you use as a front end can format your column names and there is no way you would have "Item No_" on a report anyway.